# How to create unique groups of rows separated by NULL rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

Creating some scheduling analysis, I need to be able to apply unique IDs to schedule blocks in order to count the time range of that block. Using SQL Server Management Studio.

End result currently looks something like this:

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0700 | exam | 1 |
| 0715 | exam | 2 |
| 0730 | no exam |  |
| 0745 | exam | 1 |
| 0800 | exam | 2 |
| 0815 | exam | 3 |

I need it to group those sections like so:

| a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0700 | exam | 1 | 1 |
| 0715 | exam | 2 | 1 |
| 0730 | no exam |  |  |
| 0745 | exam | 1 | 2 |
| 0800 | exam | 2 | 2 |
| 0815 | exam | 3 | 2 |
| 0830 | no exam |  |  |
| 0845 | no exam |  |  |
| 0900 | exam | 1 | 3 |
| 0915 | exam | 2 | 3 |

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I don't get where the data comes from.  Where do the rows at 0915 and 0930 come from?  What is the datatype of `a`?  How is `d` calculated?

Comment: why you decided first 3 are one group secod three second group?

Comment: It seems we need a little more explanation. Could you please supply some meaningful column names the source data and the code you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

- The first column is a time.
- You want to expand to 15 minutes intervals during some set period.
- Column d enumerates "continuous" periods of exams.

Then, this query does what you want:

```
select t, b, c,
       (case when c is not null then dense_rank() over (order by almost_d) end) as d
from (select times.t, coalesce(t.b, 'no exam') as b, c,
             sum(case when c is null then 1 else 0 end) over (order by times.t) as almost_d
      from times left join
           t
           on times.t = t.a
     ) t
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6d8985a8e9ead4018cc1dc3e563a26e6) is a db<>fiddle/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag` and `sum` windows function as follows:

```
Select a, b, c,
       Case when b = 'exam' 
            then Sum(case when prev is null or prev = 'no exam'
                          then 1
                     end) over (order by a) 
       end as d
(Select t.*,
       Lag(b) over (order by a) as prev
  From your_table t) t
```